# Regular Expression validator for number starting in negative range and ends i positive

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, web-applications, web

I am trying to resolve problem in my form.

I have a textbox, i have to validate a data it must be a digit, from range of -90 to 90
without comma, only dot allowed 
For example:
2.34 allowed
3,54 forbidden
134 forbidden
-78 allowed

i already create this expression: **^[-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+$** it supports my data formating but does not validate data range, can anybody suggest me a solution to embeed this expression.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" id="wspXformat" 
controltovalidate="textBox1" validationexpression="^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$" errormessage="Data Error" /><br />
```

i know i could make it in code but maybe there is a easier way.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [`RangeValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx):

```
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" id="wspXformat" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
     MinimumValue="-90" MaximumValue="90" Type="Double"
     Text="The value must be from -90 to 90!"  />
```

It is easier to parse the number and check for its value than come up with a complicated regular expression. If `RangeValidator`doesn't work for you, you may also consider [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx).

Comment: RangeValidator does not allow to input numers with dot,
maybe there is a solution but is it something with culture expression ?

Comment: I solved it, not sure in right way but for now it works the way i want to.

i restored in code RangeValidators created as Kobi shows and add in Web.config page globalization registry:

    <globalization
              
               culture="en-US"
               
            />

Answer (score 1):

**Checking for numbers between -90 and +90 inclusive**

A valid number has one or two significant digits before the decimal point. They might be preceded by a sign and some insignificant zeros.

Ignoring the leading sign and any leading zeroes there appear to be three cases, so perhaps a regular expression with alternation (ie `|`) would be useful. The cases are

```
value = 90
10 <= value < 90
0 <= value < 10
```

Two of these cases are "less than" which means a decimal point and some fractional digits are allowed.

There is another case to handle numbers such as `.5` which has no digits before the decimal point.

Taking these considerations leads to the expression:

```
^[-+]?0*(90(.0*)?|[1-8]\d(\.\d*)?|[0-9](\.\d*)?|\.\d*)$
```

(Tested with Notepad++ 6.5.5.)

The leading `^` and trailing `$` make it check the whole string.
The `[-+]?0*` is for the optional sign and optional leading zeroes.
The `(  |  |  |  )` delimits the four cases after the optional sign and optional leading zeroes.
The `90(.0*)?` looks after the exactly 90, with optional zero fractional part.
The `[1-8]\d(\.\d*)?` handles anything within 10 to 89 inclusive, plus an optional fractional part.
The `[0-9](\.\d*)?` handles anything within 0 to 9 inclusive, plus an optional fractional part.
The `\.\d*` handles fractions without any integral digits.

**Checking for numbers between -180 and +180 inclusive**

The same style as above can be used. First find the set of possible character strings and then combine into a regular expression.

As before, allow for an optional sign and leading zeroes. The numbers themselves can be

```
value = 180
100 <= value < 180
10 <= value < 100
0 <= value < 10
.0 <= value < 1  (and no integral part)
```

Here there are five variations. Combining all the pieces gives:

```
^[-+]?0*(180(.0*)?|(1[0-7]\d(\.\d*)?)|\d\d(\.\d*)?|\d(\.\d*)?|\.\d*)$
```

Two of the above alternatives can easily be combined. The `|\d\d(\.\d*)?|\d(\.\d*)?|` section can be changed to `|\d\d?(\.\d*)?|`. Shortening the overall expression to:

```
^[-+]?0*(180(.0*)?|(1[0-7]\d(\.\d*)?)|\d\d?(\.\d*)?|\.\d*)$
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, you example i working well,

gives me a little understanding of regular expressions and i was able do make regular expression for range from -180 to 180

just for sure could you take a look fo my expression:

^[-+]?0*(180(.0*)?|[0-9]\d(\.\d*)?|(1[0-7]\d(\.\d*)?)|\.\d*)$

seems to doing the job fine, but i would like to know that i didn't make any wrong statements

Comment: @lolek Your 180 code is a good start but it does not allow for numbers between 0 and 10, eg `9` or `6.4321`. Your try also includes `|(1[0-7]\d(\.\d*)?)|` where the outer set of brackets are unnecessary.